# How do I turn down volume in php?

Tags: php

Can I turn down volume or possibly mute the computer while they are on my website?

Comment: No. Volume is controlled by the client, whereas PHP is a server-side language.

Comment: Also, why? If you don't want your website to emit sound, just don't put any sound emitting things on it. What else do you have to do fiddling around with the user's system, muting their iTunes?

Comment: I was curious if PHP could actually do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, PHP is a server-side technology and has nothing to do with the client computer.

I doubt you'll be able to do this with JavaScript either.

Answer (score 2):

The volume of the computer of visitors of your website?

No. PHP has absolutely nothing to do with that, and even client-side scripts (i.e. Javascript) don't have this kind of access to the system.

You can at best mute the server the PHP script is running on.
The admin in the server room may thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not with PHP.

If you are using an `<embed>` to play audio, you could *try* to use the embed tag's `volume` attribute, but good luck with it actually being used by the browser.